# Make things happen in order in android

Tags: android, dialog

Im having trouble making things happen in order instead of together in android.

For instance when a user clicks a `Button`, I want a `ProgressDialog` to be displayed first, then dismissed, and then `TextView` changed. Would I need to make a method for each of these or is it something i can implement to make this happen.

Thanks for anyone who helps.

Comment: You'll have to specify your problem more or show off some code-examples.

Comment: Have you tried something so far ? Show us some code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an AsyncTask to accomplish this. Override `doInBackground` and use `publishProgress` and `onProgressUpdate` to update your progress bar. Then, in `onPostExecute`, update your TextView.

An example (without the `publishProgress` and `onProgressUpdate`):

```
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mTextView.setText("All Done");
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Welcome.this, "Progress title", "Progress message", true);
        }

    }.execute((Void) null);
```

Comment: Prentice the only problem is that ever time the user clicks the button the text will change...This means i will have to implement this each time it is clicked?

Comment: You can create a new instance of the AsyncTask in your button onClick.

Comment: Could you give me an example like the one above, except add the instance in the button click. Thanks man youve been a great help so far.

Comment: DUDE! You saved me man! The code worked i implemented the AsyncTask and Walla!! Thanks man. Now the only problem is i dont want to implement this everytime the button is clicked. lol If you could show me a better way i would definitely appreciate it. Your awesome man!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an [OnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html) and set it on your `ProgressDialog` using `ProgressDialog#setOnDismissListener(DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)` -- See [ProgressDialog#setOnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29)